# this.is(":checked") not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following code to loop through all the checkboxes in my form.  The boxes are gerenated dynamicaly from a php script so I won't know the names or the number of check boxes.

I need to find out which checkboxes have been ticked so I only pass those ones to the php script that handles the form.

```
 $("#panelform input:checkbox").each(function () {
    if(this.is(":checked")){
    fields = fields+"&"+this.name+"="+this.value;
}
});
```

When the script gets to the this.is(":checked") it errors but being jquery my console doesn't show me any error messages just stops.

if I alert or console.log "this" after the first line I get the form field so I know that that much works.

Comment: What do you mean "being jquery my console doesn't show me any error messages"? You should have seen something like `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'is'`

Comment: JavaScript errors show up in the console even if you are using jQuery. The browser doesn't know/care what frameworks you use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try with

```
 if($(this).is(":checked")){
```

since `this` is just a reference to the node in the DOM (and you need instead to use the `jQuery` wrapper to chain the method `is()`.

Comment: The explanation is that `is()` is a jQuery method, not a standard JavaScript one.

Comment: Thanks lol I worked that out a couple of mins ago was being a moron. I'll make this as correct when it lets me.

Comment: someone could explain the downvote, please? by OP admission this solves his problem... :(

Comment: It solves the problem, but it is completely pointless and (in my opinion) stupid to put the browser through all the trouble of creating a whole new jQuery object, just to get a property that's already right there.

Comment: well, the usage of jQuery here is obviously subjective even if it is less performant: OP could simply check `if (this.checked)` but since he're using a jQuery construct it seems logical to give him the explanation of the error. But I respect anyway your point of view :)

Comment: Downvoting an answer for not optimizing the code presented in the question is stupid.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
if( this.checked)
```

`this` is the plain DOM node, `checked` is its property to tell you if it's checked or not. Creating a whole new jQuery object just to see if a property is set is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

In that contect, `this` refers to the DOM element, not the jQuery object - and DOM elements have no method `is()`. You can wrap it in a jQuery object if you want to use is method:

```
if($(this).is(":checked")){
```

or use the DOM Element's `checked` property:

```
if(this.checked){
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).is(':checked')
```

if you want to serialize your form try this

```
$('your-form-selector').serializeArray()
```